# Running multiple mesos slaves locally

Tags: installation, cluster-computing, bigdata, local, mesos

I'm trying to run a test cluster locally following this guide https://mesosphere.com/2014/07/07/installing-mesos-on-your-mac-with-homebrew/

Currently, I'm able to have a master running at localhost:5050 and a slave running at the default port 5051 (with slave id say S0). However, when I tried to start another slave at a different port, it re-registered itself as S0 and the master console only showed 1 activated slave. Does anybody know how would I start another slave S1? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you specify a another work_dir?
E.g.

> sudo /usr/local/sbin/mesos-slave --master=localhost:5050 --port=5052 --    work_dir=/tmp/mesos2

To explain a bit why this is needed/ where the error you saw came from.
Mesos supports so called [slave recovery](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/slave-recovery/) for helping with upgrades and error recovery.

Therefore when starting a slave, it will check its work_dir for checkpoint and try to recover that state (i.e. reconnect to still running executors).
In your case as both slaves wanted to start from the same working directory, the second one tried to recover the checkpoint of the still running first slave...

P.S. I should probably replace all the above occurences of slave with worker (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-1478), but I hope this is easier to read.

Comment: Why would that help? Maybe adding some information on recovery might be helpful for the OP. :)

Comment: @Till Hi Till, if you can add some more details for why this works would be great! THanks a bunch!

Comment: The work_dir is where the slave stores its checkpointed data, including executor/task process IDs and status, as well as the slaveID that it should try to reregister as. Thus, once the first slave has checkpointed its id to its work_dir, if the second slave tries to use the same work_dir, it will reregister itself as the same slave, kicking out the original.